# drupal views: how to invoke swftools media player for emfields?

Tags: drupal-6, flash, drupal-views, media-player

I am using swftools to display filefields (Drupal 6).
Now I would like to use swftools to display the custom-url *emfields* (embedded media fields).  For example, if my emaudio field contains the url *http://example.com/myaudio.mp3*.  I would like to use the swftools audio player to play this mp3 file.

I know how to invoke the swftools player, if I am displaying a *node* that contains an emfield.  I use hook_preprocess_content_field() to replace $items[0]['view'] with swf($items[0]['value']):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_content_field(&$vars) {
  foreach ($vars['items']as $index=>$arr){
    // Note: 
    // Emfield's custom_url video provider is called "zzz_custom_url".
    // Emfield's custom_url audio provider is called "custom_url"
    if ($arr['provider']=='zzz_custom_url' || $arr['provider']=='custom_url'){
      $vars['items'][$index]['view'] = swf($arr['value']);
    }
  }
}
```

But I do not know how to invoke the swf player if I am displaying a *view* that contains an emfield.  That is, I have not been able to figure out how to pull off a similar trick when I am displaying a *view* rather than a *node*.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution.
I created a views template to theme my emaudio field,

> views-view-field--field-my-emaudio-embed.tpl.php

Here is the content of the template:

```
$data = $row->{$field->field_alias};
print swf($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:
Create the custom formatter "SWF Emaudio", as described below. Then select this formatter to display your custom-url emaudio field, from within the cck or views UI.

```
function mymodule_field_formatter_info() {
  $formatters = array();
  $formatters['swf_emaudio'] = array(
      'label' => t('SWF Emaudio'),
  'field types' => array('emaudio'),
    );
}
function mymodule_theme() {
  $themes['mymodule_formatter_swf_emaudio'] = array(
      'arguments' => array('element' => NULL, 'options' => array()),
      'function' => 'theme_o4_mediatools_formatter_swf_emaudio',
    );
  }
  return ($themes);
}
function theme_mymodule_formatter_swf_emaudio($element, $options = array()) {
  $embed_value = $element['#item']['value'] ;
  $output = swf($embed_value, $options);
  return ($output);
}
```